# continuously print the last line of a file Linux termin

Tags: linux, background, terminal

Two questions, but only stuck on one. Feel that I need the first one so someone can help me make sense of it.

4) Use cat and /dev/null to create an empty file.

5) Start a background process that continuously prints the last line of the file created in #4..

So what i did for number 4 was:

```
cat /dev/null > emptyfile
```

This created an empty file. Okay so I am happy with that. The next question however confuses me. How can I read the last line of an empty file? Better yet how do I continuously do this? Running it in the background isn't a problem. Anyone have any ideas? We haven't covered scripting yet so I don't think that plays a role. As always, thanks for the help.

Comment: You can `echo -n > nonemptyfile` to empty the contents of a file. You can `touch emptyfile` to create an empty file.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use the UNIX command "tail" with the -f option. That will continuously print out contents from the file to the terminal as it is added to the file.

Example:

```
tail -f emptyfile
```

You can terminate the tail process by typing Ctrl + C.

Comment: "continuously print out contents from the file" is not the requirement.

Comment: Um, yes. The question mentions continuously reading the last line two times.

Comment: If I append 5 lines to the file then it will output 5 lines. If I append 0 lines then it will output 0.

Answer (score 4):

doesn't `tail -f FILE_NAME` help?

Answer (score 2):

`tail` with `watch` or a loop with a delay.

Also, neither `cat` nor `/dev/null` are required.

```
> emptyfile
```

`tail` and `watch` example:

`watch tail -n 1 log.txt` will always show the last line of the log file. Default interval in `watch` is 2 seconds.

Comment: Brilliant answer! ```watch tail -n 1 log.txt``` is just the thing I wanted!